# AJAX not posting in Firefox, working in other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

By title I know this question appears several times and I have studied them all and tried hints found in the answers to no avail. I have 5 videos on a page and want to register in my DB when one is played. Here is my JS placed in the footer of my page:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(".cssvid").on('play',function(event){
        var vid_id=$(this).attr('id');

       $.ajax({
            url:"ajax-css-video-view.php",
            method:"POST",
            cache: false,
            data:{ "vid_id": vid_id },
            success: function() {
                alert(vid_id);
            },
            error: function(err){
                alert(err);
            }
       });

   });          

});
```

I'm just passing a single variable, the id, to my php script, which is saving it to the database. This is working in Chrome, Safari, etc. Just not Firefox.

Note the alert vid_id in Success. I get this alert in all browsers except Firefox. I can move the alert up above ajax and it will alert the id in firefox. So I know on play and getting the id is  working in Firefox.

Also, I set up an image with the class 'cssvid' and changed to on click and it  works every time in Firefox.

Another possible clue, I enabled console on the browsers. In Chrome and Safari I can see the parameters when a video is clicked. On Firefox it says, "No parameters". But in my research I see there may be a possible bug in Mozilla for parameters in console. So I don't know if I can trust that as a clue.

I've run out of ideas. This should be a simple little script doing a simple job. What am I missing for Firefox?

Comment: Try quote your object key, e.g. `data:{ "vid_id": vid_id },`

Comment: Any indication that the call is even being attempted? Network requests, etc.? Anything in the server logs? If you add an `error` handler in addition to `success`, does it report anything?

Comment: Not going to change much but note that `$(function(){ })` and `$(document).ready()` are the same ...no need to repeat

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using. The `method:` option was added in 1.9, it was called `type:` before that.

Comment: Does the console show an error code coming from the server?

Comment: Thanks. I added the quotes (LGSon) and took out the redundancy (charlietfl). Using jQuery v1.11.1. The console isn't showing any errors. When I click to play it logs an XHR event with no parameters.

Comment: I added the error handler and it does not report any error when clicking play. I also added cache: false even though I don't thing caching is an issue with post. I've reflected the changes to my code in the post above. The results are still the same so far.

Comment: How did you add quotes to the data? Best bet is to do `data:JSON.stringify({ "vid_id": vid_id }),`.

Comment: Also, your success function should include the returned data: `success: function(data) {`. I think it needs to be there even if nothing is returned (??).

Comment: @wazz Of course, thanks....deleted, 3.10 am so must be time to sleep now

Comment: apparently this one stumped everyone. If I ever find a solution I'll answer it for others.